# Generic Training Phrase in Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a mock interview Action that asks a specific set of questions in a specific order, regardless of what the user says in response to each question. How can I set up the intent in Dialogflow to accept any phrase from a user to trigger the next question as the response?

Ex of the dialog path:

```
User: "I want to practice for an interview"
Google: "Question 1: tell me about yourself"
User: [says literally anything]
Google: "Great job. Question 2..."
User: [says literally anything]
Google: "Okay! Question 3..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Dialogflow, you can create an intent that accepts any input by taking the user utterances and marking them as `@sys.any`.

Then you can do one of the following:

- Use Dialogflow contexts to make the next step dependent on the first (this is good if you want to do *everything* in Dialogflow)
- Keep track of the conversational state in your webhook using the `app.data` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good ways to handle what you want, the best solution will depend on your other needs.

If you're using a fulfillment webhook, you can handle this as part of the [Fallback Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents). Make sure the checkbox to use fulfillment is on for the Fallback Intent, and you'll be sent everything that the user says that doesn't meet other structures. You'll need to keep count of how many times you've been called and you can store this as a parameter in a [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts), as part of the `app.data` session storage object, or as part of the `app.userStore` cross-session storage object. Your webhook will return the next question as a response.

If you want to avoid fulfillments and handle it through Dialogflow, you can use the same general idea, but you will need to keep track of which question you're on for each time. You can do this by creating multiple Fallback Intents with each one having as an [Incoming Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) a context named after which question you're expecting the user to answer (say "question_1") and the [Outgoing Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) named after the question that is in the reply (for example, "question_2").